# Describe the span of the given vectors geometrically and algebraically

Tags: linear-algebra, span

Describe the span of the given vectors geometrically and algebraically:

$\pmatrix{1\\0\\-1}$, $\pmatrix{-1\\1\\0}$, $\pmatrix{0\\-1\\1}$.

I have figured out that these vectors are linearly dependent since the system with the following augmented matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 &0 & 0\\0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

led me to a parametric solution

$$t\pmatrix{1\\0\\-1} + t\pmatrix{-1\\1\\0} + t\pmatrix{0\\-1\\1} = 0$$
(so another solutions exist besides the trivial one).

How do I now determine what kind of a geometric object it represents? It can't be a 3D space since there are not 3 linearly independent vectors in the set.

I assume that it is an equation of a plane since it does not look like that any two vectors are a linear combination of third one (such a case would result in a line in 3D). How do I choose which two vectors from the three to use as directional vectors defining the plane? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your three vectors $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$ are linearly dependent but the first two are linearly independent.
Therefore $\operatorname{span}(\vec a,\vec b,\vec c)=\operatorname{span}(\vec a,\vec b)$.
The span is a 2D plane.
You could use any two vectors to do this, since any of your three vectors can be written as a linear combination of the other two.

Comment: And the algebraic definition would be the plane $ x + y + z = 0 $, and I got the $ a = b = c = 1$ coefficients of the normal vector by taking the cross product of vectors $\vec a$, $\vec b$. Correct? Thanks.

Comment: @pseudomarvin, yes, correct! There is another option as well, but it's not necessarily any easier: You could observe that the components of any of your three vectors sum to zero, so $x+y+z=0$ must hold in their span as well. If you do it this way, you will also need to check that all vectors of this form are indeed in the span; a dimension argument is possible here.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is worth noting also that since your vectors transform to each other under permutations of the 3 axes, the plane which you seek is normal to the vector $(1,1,1)$. You can verify this by computing the inner product of this vector with your 3 vectors. This gives a nice way to visualize the plane. It is a plane which is tangent to the origin such that the 3 positive axes are all on one side, equi-angular from that plane.

Comment: I don't quite understand this step: "the vectors transform to each other under permutations of the 3 axes". Do you mean that by adding a linear combination of the vectors $(1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, $(0, 0, 1)$ to one of the vectors I can get the other two vectors? (Probably not since this applies to any two vectors in 3D right?) Could you also elaborate on the conclusion "[therefore] the plane which you seek is normal to the vector (1, 1, 1)"? That seems like a pretty handy concept of which I have not been aware so far. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: If you swap the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, your 3 vectors become $(0,1,-1)$, $(1,-1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$. These are actually the negatives of your original 3 vectors, but in a different order. Therefore they span the same plane. All other permutations of the $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ axes do the same thing. This tells you that the plane must have the same angles to each of the axes. And then the clincher is that they all have zero inner product with the vector $(1,1,1)$.